# Can you use -Filter on Get-ADUser to filter out empty fields?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a way to filter out empty fields when grabbing the data from the Active Directory and then inserting it into a SQL table? When I used `-Filter` on `Get-ADUser` I don't think this is the correct syntax for doing this.

It fails saying

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input

```
$ADARRAY = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Users" -Recursive |
           Get-ADUser -Filter {-not (Mail -like "*")} -Properties Mail)

foreach($OBJECT in $ADARRAY) {
    $NAME = $OBJECT.Name 
    $USER = $OBJECT.SamAccountName
    $EMAIL = $OBJECT.Mail

    $INSERT = "INSERT $TABLE VALUES ('$USER','$EMAIL', '$NAME')"
    $SQL.CommandText = $INSERT 

    $SQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$SQLCON.Close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting that error message because `Get-ADUser` can **either** read input from the pipeline **or** use the parameter `-Filter`. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) you'll see that the cmdlet has 3 parameter sets:

```
Get-ADUser
   [-AuthType <ADAuthType>]
   [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   -Filter <String>
   [-Properties <String[]>]
   [-ResultPageSize <Int32>]
   [-ResultSetSize <Int32>]
   [-SearchBase <String>]
   [-SearchScope <ADSearchScope>]
   [-Server <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

```
Get-ADUser
   [-AuthType <ADAuthType>]
   [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   [-Identity] <ADUser>
   [-Partition <String>]
   [-Properties <String[]>]
   [-Server <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

```
Get-ADUser
   [-AuthType <ADAuthType>]
   [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   -LDAPFilter <String>
   [-Properties <String[]>]
   [-ResultPageSize <Int32>]
   [-ResultSetSize <Int32>]
   [-SearchBase <String>]
   [-SearchScope <ADSearchScope>]
   [-Server <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

The second of these would be used for reading pipeline input from `Get-ADGroupMember` (via the parameter `-Identity`), but when specifying the parameter `-Filter` you're forcing the use of the first one, which does not accept your pipeline input.

Also, judging from your code you actually want user objects that *do* have a `mail` attribute.

Use a `Where-Object` filter like this and the code should do what you want:

```
$ADARRAY = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Users' -Recursive |
           Get-ADUser -Properties Mail |
           Where-Object { $_.Mail -like '*' }
```

If you really want user objects that *don't* have a `mail` attribute change the condition `$_.Mail -like '*'` to `$_.Mail -notlike '*'`.

Answer (score 4):

You're close, but `Filter` takes a filter string not a script block (try `Get-Help Get-ADUser`).

This should get you what you need:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Mail -notlike '*'"
```

[This page explains more on the filter syntax for AD.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/04/14/active-directory-powershell-advanced-filter-part-ii/)